# I used Select in Python Selenium but not able to select values

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Unit test in Python and I used Select in Python Selenium but not able to select values, so please suggest me to select values from Drop down box

Please check below is my code:

```
self.login_element= Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="field_DOBDay"]'))

        self.login_element.select_by_visible_text('01')
        self.login_element.select_by_index('1')
        self.login_element.select_by_value('1')
```

Comment: what is the exception stack trace ? and share the respective HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have information about your html source but,

Please try following code with specific optionText, option_text should exactly match with options text:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name="field_DOBDay"]/option[text()='option_text']").click()
```